# Set of all $a\in\mathbb Z$ that are coprime to $b\in\mathbb Z$

Tags: notation, congruences

$\newcommand\Z{\mathbb{Z}}$I'm looking for a standard or reasonable notation for

$$ \{a\in\Z : a\perp b\} = \{a\in\Z : \gcd(a,b)=1\} $$

My problem is that:

- It is not $\Z/b\Z^*$, since for me, $1\neq b+1$.
- It cannot be $\Z_b$, since that are the $b$-adic integers.

So I'm unable to find something fitting. It is not crucial (I can write it out every time), but it would be helpful. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you could write this as
$$
\bigcup \left(\mathbb Z\big/b\mathbb Z\right)^*,
$$
where the union just throws the invertible cosets in $\mathbb Z\big/b\mathbb Z$ together.

Anyway, this isn't standard in any way, nor is it more comprehensible than defining some notation like
$$
\mathcal C_b = \{\,a\in\mathbb Z \mid \gcd(a,b)=1\,\}
$$
on your own. Where $\mathcal C$ is supposed to suggest coprime.

You could also just write "Let $a\in\mathbb Z$ with $(a,b)=1$", since $(a,b)$ is often used to denote $\gcd(a,b)$ in this context.

Comment: You're right that introducing a new notation will likely be necessary. I use only $\gcd(a,b)=1$ or not, so I prefer to use the symbol $\perp$. Which made me thinking: Would $(b\mathbb Z)^\perp$ do the job (of course properly defined)?

Comment: Wouldn't $b^\perp$ or something like $\perp_b$ me more accurate then? I don't see how the set is more related to $b\mathbb Z$ than $b$ itself.

Comment: That's probably right, but $b^\perp$ doesn't so much look like a set, so I converge to $(b)^\perp$ :) Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a standard notation for the set of representatives of the invertible elements under a quotient map of rings.

The set is the union of all the arithmetic progressions ${\cal P}_b(a)=a+{\Bbb Z}b$ as $a$ varies in a set of representatives of $(\Bbb Z/b\Bbb Z)^\times$. If you want a symbol for that, an option could be
$$
\cal P_b^\times=\bigcup_{a\in(\Bbb Z/b\Bbb Z)^\times}{\cal P}_b(a).
$$